# Passing enum to android native module

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-modules, titanium-android

I am passing `enum` to the android native module, but I get this error at run time:

> [ERROR] :  JNIUtil: !!! Unable to convert unknown Java object class
>   'miy.Enums$Status' to Js value !!!
>
> [INFO] :   libc: Fatal signal 11
>   (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 6614 (KrollRuntimeThr)

The above error is displayed before the function in the native module is even called, so it seems like the issue is in JNI layer.

So how do I pass `enum` to a native module?

Answer (score 0):

Use @Kroll.constant instead (https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.map/blob/master/android/src/ti/map/MapModule.java).

Comment: so can i not pass the enum directly to native module ? because i am getting the above error even before the function in native module is called
so how can i use @Kroll.constant

Comment: You can pass to and get from native module only [such types](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Android_Module_Architecture-section-43289000_AndroidModuleArchitecture-TypeConversions).
Is it you module?